# Add Function to JavaScript Object using Object.Create

Tags: javascript, oop, object-create

I'm trying to use Object.Create in JavaScript.  I currently have the following code:

```
var vehicle = {
        getModel: function () {
        console.log( "The model of this vehicle is.." + this.model );
    }
};

var car = Object.create(vehicle, {
    "id": {
       value: 9,         
    },
    "model": {
       value: "Ford",  
    }
});

var van = Object.create(vehicle, {
  "id": {
     value: 10,    
   },
    "model": {
      value: "Big Van",
      enumerable: true
   },
    "make": {
      value: "Warrior",      
   },
    "getMake": function () {
       console.log( "The make of this vehicle is.." + this.make );
   }
});
```

I've tried to add a function to van for getMake but I get the error:

> TypeError: Property 'getMake' of object # is not a function when I call:

van.getMake();

Is this possible?  How do you do it?

Comment: I have never used `Object.create`...

Comment: Not only have I never used it, but I didn't know it even existed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Properties created that way are not enumerable by default.  This may be causing your issue.

Try this(untested):

```
"getMake": { value: function () {
       console.log( "The make of this vehicle is.." + this.make )
   }, enumerable: true };
```

*Edit* It looks like this is working because we are passing an object and not just the value.  The enumerable is unnecessary.

Comment: No need for the property to be enumerable.

Comment: I'm with @dystroy, I'd even argue that the property is best defined as `enumerable: false`, when iterating an object (`for (var p in obj)`), you generally don't want to deal with the methods

Comment: But the default behaviour is to list all enumerable properties, and methods are enumerable by default.So its good to go with the enumerable:true as it is more towards the expected default behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass an object defining the property, not just the value :

```
 "getMake": {value:function () {
     console.log( "The make of this vehicle is.." + this.make );
 }}
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Note that the usual way to do OOP in Javascript isn't in using Object.create but in using [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).

Comment: In my own opinion it's ugly, useless and **[slow](http://jsperf.com/object-create-vs-constructor-vs-object-literal/7)**. But, as most js coders I never use Object.create so I may miss some of its advantages.